# Is there a way to pipe the mail output to a file?

Tags: email, postfix

Say for example that I used the command

```
sendmail foo@bar.com < email.txt
```

Is there any way to configure postfix to send the contents of email.txt to a file, instead of to foo@bar.com?

The environment I'm working in does not have external network access, so it can't send mail normally. But I have programs like Jira that send out email notifications, whose functionality I'd like to test